# Neo4j results as png file

Tags: neo4j, export, png

The neo4j browser can be used to view and export the result of a cypher query as an image. Is there a way to do this using the REST/Java or any other API interface?

I can probably get the result as a Json and visualize the result using linkurious but the inbuilt neo4j visualization is better for my purpose.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of options.  Coming at it from the REST API, there are a few client packages available.  One is `RNeo4j` for `R`.  The README for the package includes a section on visualization.  See that [here](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j#visualizations)